# Parse "puppet agent" run

Tags: python, parsing, puppet, puppet-enterprise

We are using `Puppet 3.7.4` to manage our servers (RedHat & Windows server).

We have a `python API` that runs the remote command `puppet agent -t` on the servers.
Sometimes new classes are being applied, sometimes classes are failed.

The result is being splitted to `stdout` and `stderr`.
Is there any best practice how to parse that output?
I would like to present what happened to the server in a "pretty way".
For example:

> new user created: User1

or

> failed to create new user: User1. Because: XXX

I have no any ideas how to parse puppet agent`s output.
Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: *Any ideas?*: regex, the `re` module to be specific. You may also add an example output from puppet.

Comment: If you are using python then I would recommend using the PuppetDB's Python API to grab that information.